# Reading laravel .env values in windows terminal and use them as credentials for mysql in a batch file

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, laravel, batch-file, cmd

I created a .bat script to import several .csv in my DB for a Laravel project.

At first, I was using python and each time it took an eternity to restore long files, so I decided to back up those tables and restore them with MySQL.

old .bat file

```
echo.
echo - Rebuilding database
php artisan migrate:fresh

echo.
echo - Importing animals data
cd py_animalimporter
python importer.py
cd ..

echo.
echo - Importing colors data
cd py_colorimporter
python importer.py
cd ..

echo.
echo - Rebuilding database
php artisan db: seed

echo.
echo - Importing places data
cd py_placeimporter
python importer.py
cd ..

echo.
echo - Starting local server
php artisan serve
```

New .bat file

```
echo.
echo - Rebuilding database
php artisan migrate:fresh

echo.
echo - Restoring sql backup
mysql -u username -p test_local < backup.sql
password

echo.
echo - Rebuilding database
php artisan db: seed

echo.
echo - Importing places data
cd py_placeimporter
python importer.py
cd ..

echo.
echo - Starting local server
php artisan serve
```

My python scripts read MySQL credentials from my laravel.env file (thanks to dotenv library), unfortunately, I can't figure how to do anything similar from the windows terminal.

.env file

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308
DB_DATABASE=test_local
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

.py files example

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
import os
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

def connectDb():
    # Retrieve db credentials from .env
    env_path = '../.env'
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

    db_host = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
    db_port = os.getenv("DB_PORT")
    db_database = os.getenv("DB_DATABASE")
    db_username = os.getenv("DB_USERNAME")
    db_password = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")

    if db_password is None:
        db_password = ''

    return mysql.connector.connect(user=db_username, password=db_password,
                                    host=db_host,
                                    port=db_port,
                                    database=db_database)

def insertPrimaryColour(hex,color):
    try:
        cnx = connectDb()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("] Wrong Credentials")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("] No Existing Database")
        else:
            print("] " + err)
    else:
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

        query = f"INSERT INTO dom_colors(`order`,hex,id_translation) VALUES(0,'{hex}','{color}');"
        cursor.execute(query)
        insert_id = cursor.lastrowid

        cnx.commit()
        cnx.close()

    return insert_id
```

Alternately, I could use python to restore the DB but everything I tried didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution with Python sending code to the Windows Terminal!

Here's the Python Script that now I call from the batch file

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
import os

def restoreDB():
    # Retrieve DB credentials from .env
    env_path = '.env'
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

    #db_host = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
    #db_port = os.getenv("DB_PORT")
    db_database = os.getenv("DB_DATABASE")
    db_username = os.getenv("DB_USERNAME")
    db_password = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")

    if db_password is "":
        mysqlLogin = "mysql -u "+db_username+" "+db_database+" < backup.sql"
    else:
        mysqlLogin = "mysql -u "+db_username+" --password='"+db_password+"' "+db_database+" < backup.sql"
    os.system('cmd /c "%s"' % mysqlLogin)

restoreDB()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make ad os indipendent solution you can try to use *subprocess*.

You can use in this way:

```
mysqlLogin = [...]

process = subprocess.Popen(mysqlLogin, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
```

This code line will run the command contained in *mysqlLogin* and wait for his termination.

You can also configure standard output redirection with *stdout* paramters.

Here is the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html